# API Orchestration in rest assured during run time

Tags: rest, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

How to build a post request after taking some values from other post response on the run time in rest assured.

Suppose I have a big Json file which I am going to send it as request modifying just 2 or 3 key's values taking that value from another response.

Comment: Add code trials/snippet and limit to specific question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-requisite: Add the below dependency in your Maven.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180130</version>
</dependency>
```

Say you have a post response body in the string format ***response.getBody().asString()*** from the first request as below,

```
{
"id": 13245,
"name": "firstName",
"phone": 1234567890
}
```

Convert the above string to a JSONObject and manipulate data as below

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.getBody().asString());

    jsonObject.put("id", 54321);

    jsonObject.put("name", "lastName");

    System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
```

Your output will print as following

```
{"phone":1234567890,"name":"lastName","id":54321}
```